# Is “Lend a cachet” popular phrase?

Tags: phrases

I found the phrase “*lend a cachet*” in the following sentence of the New York Times’ (November 11) article, titled [“Picking brand names in China is a business itself”](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/11/12/world/asia/picking-brand-names-in-china-is-a-business-itself.html):

> “For some products, having a foreign-sounding name *lends a cachet* that a true Chinese name would lack. Many upscale brands like Cadillac (Ka di la ke), or Hilton (Xi er dun), employ phonetic translations that mean nothing in Chinese. Rolls-Royce (Laosi-Laisi) includes two Chinese characters for “labor” and “plants” that more or less have become standard usage in foreign names - all to achieve a distinct foreign look and sound. “

I understand “lend a cachet” implies “give prestige, or add prestigious image” from the context of the above statement.

I checked both Cambridge and Merriam-Webster online dictionaries to find neither of them registers “lend a cachet.”

On Google, I found the following examples of the phrase in use.

- Her presence *lends a certain cachet to* the company. – [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lend).
- Where's the party? Sun Bowl *lends cachet to* Camino Real's New Year's bash. - El Paso Times.

From the above, I realized “lend a cachet” is a simple combination of “lend” and “cachet,” not an idiom that I first conceived. However, is “lend a cachet” frequently used phrasing as opposed to other plain expressions, say “give prestige or “add a fashionable (Western) image”?

Comment: In the second-to-last line, do you mean *cachet*?

Comment: @Mahnax. Sorry. It's a typo. I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: I figured as much, but you never know, I suppose.

Comment: The phrase is actually *lends cachet*; *lends a cachet that a true Chinese name would lack*, as the full clause, is quite normal, but ? *lends a cachet* without context would be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Charting "lend cachet" vs "lend prestige"]
Charting ["lend cachet" vs. "lend prestige"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lend%20cachet,lend%20prestige&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows "lend prestige" to be much more commonly used. You get a similar disparity between "cachet" and "prestige" on their own.

So I wouldn't say "lend [a] cachet" is a popular phrasing, although it's probably one that I would use (such as in the example from MW Unabridged: *"Being a guard gave you a certain cachet."*)

Comment: 'Gives a certain cachet' is the form I'm most familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

In everyday speech, *lends a cachet* is not heard too often. In formal speech, it is much more likely to be heard, but still is not incredibly popular. *Give prestige* and *add a fashionable image* are more likely to be heard in everyday speech, as is something  like *gives an air of sophistication*.